# how to edit a column of a table row without affecting the other columns in my database olin php?

Tags: php, database

how to edit a column of a table row without affecting the other columns in my database olin php?

```
$sql=my_sqlquery("UPDATE grade SET Studno='$Studno',Prelim='$Prelim',Midterm='$Midterm',Final='$Final' WHERE Studno='$Studno'");
```

Comment: Just leave out the columns you don't want to change.

Comment: don't update the column which you don't want to update in SET simple !

Answer (score 0):

Update it using the Primary Key field in your database by having the primary key, usually the record id in the where condition. Be specific when updating records, or you can accidentally change data you don't mean to.

The best way to avoid problems is to always run a select with the same where condition as your update statement so you can see what the data is gonna be before you execute the update statement.

Please ensure you bind to escape your sql. In this example id would be the tables primary key field. You can find this in mysql by running

```
DESCRIBE tablename;
```

Then do an update using mysqli or a PDO to escape the values.

```
UPDATE tablename SET field1=:field1value, field2=:field2value WHERE something=:somevalue AND id = :recordid
```